# Modify live call status twilio

Tags: twilio

I want to  modify the live callStatus of twilio using it's REST API. I have listed all the available queue phone number and want to modify callStatus from queued to call in-progress  or ringing.How do i get this?.

Comment: Do you mean move a call from a queue to ring someone? Also, what language are you using - PHP, Java, Ruby, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

You can use the REST API to dequeue a specific call waiting in a queue.  To do this you [make a POST request to the CallSid you want to redirect](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/member#instance-post-example-2), but you have to do it through the Members resource.  As part of that HTTP request, you pass in a Url parameter.  Doing that tells Twilio to redirect that call out of the queue, make an request to that Url and then start executing the TwiML returned.

```
$member = $client->account->queues->get('QU5ef8732a3c49700934481addd5ce1659')->members->get("CA5ef8732a3c49700934481addd5ce1659");
$member->update(array(
    "Url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml",
    "Method" => "POST"
));
```

Now, to make this request you need to know the SID of the Queue you want to work with and the CallSid of the Queue Member you want to redirect.

Lets walk through getting those two values.

**Locating a Queue SID**

There are any number of ways to get a Queues SID.  If you use the REST API to create Queues then your app could save the Queue SID each time it [creates a new Queue](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/queue#list-post):

```
$queue = $client->account->queues->create("newqueue", array());
echo $queue->sid;  //save the sid in a db or some other store
```

or you can use the [REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/queue#list-get) to [list all of your Queues](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/queue#list-get-example-1).  For example, here I am using REST API to get the list of [Queue resources](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/queue#instance), loop over them and print the current average wait time:

```
// Loop over the list of queues and echo a property for each one
foreach ($client->account->queues as $queue) {
    echo $queue->average_wait_time;
}
```

If you wanted to find a specific Queue by using its Friendly Name, you could modify this to loop to look at the [*friendly_name* parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/queue#instance-properties) of each Queue.

```
// Loop over the list of queues and echo a property for each one
foreach ($client->account->queues as $queue) {
    echo $queue->friendly_name;
}
```

In this case I'm simply printing out the Friendly Name of each Queue.

**Locating the CallSid**

Once you have the Queue SID you next need to get the CallSid of the call you want to redirect.  There are different ways to do this.

You could use the Members resource to list all of the calls waiting in that Queue:

```
foreach ($client->account->queues->get('QU5ef8732a3c49700934481addd5ce1659')->members as $member) {
    echo $member->CallSid;
}
```

Each member resource gives you some information about that member, including the CallSid.

If you didn't know the specific calls CallSid and wanted to locate the call based on something like the callers phone number, you can use the Calls resource:

```
$call = $client->account->calls->getIterator(0, 50, array(
    "Status" => "in-progress",
    "From" => "+15555555555"));
$callsid = $call->CallSid;
```

Here I am asking Twilio to return me a Call resource whose From phone number is +15555555555" and whose status is "in-progress", and then grabbing that Calls CallSid.

**Redirecting the Queued Caller**

Now that I have both the Queue SID and the CallSid I can redirect the caller out of the Queue and to another experience:

```
$member = $client->account->queues->get('QU5ef8732a3c49700934481addd5ce1659')->members->get("CA5ef8732a3c49700934481addd5ce1659");
$member->update(array(
    "Url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml",
    "Method" => "POST"
));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually i am talking about incase of inbound call that are in queue. If receiver is busy then my phone call are put in the queue right. I have listed all the available inbound queued phone number. If there are five phone number in queue such as caller1 phone number , caller2 phone number, caller3 phone number , caller4 phone number and caller5 phone number. So i want to pick up any one of queue phone number to talk with her/him and want to hangup current active call . And one more thing there is no  rate limits for inbound call.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.  I updated my answer to hopefully have what you are looking for.

Comment: I am using https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call to list current phone number queue list. $sid = "AC873be184fe958e352d54b2e20c82be93"; 
$token = "{{ auth_token }}"; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);
 
// Loop over the list of calls and echo a property for each one
foreach ($client->account->calls->getIterator(0, 50, array(
        "Status" => "queued",
  
    )) as $call
) {
    echo $call->from;
} this will not give me queueSid . It only give me callSid. But i am trying to get queue list using https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/queue will not give me current queue number.

Comment: So how do i get queue sid and callsid togther.

Comment: I expanded my answer with details on getting the CallSid and From number for members of a queue.

Comment: If i used [Memeber](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/member#list) then syntax like this $member = $client->account->queues->get('QU5ef8732a3c49700934481addd5ce1659')->members->get("CA5ef8732a3c49700934481addd5ce1659"); so i need Both queueSid and sid we have sid from [call] (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#instance-properties). But how do i get queueSid. Please explain me with some example.